# getting ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR sometimes for some images and ajax requests

Tags: google-chrome, networking, quic

If I load my website in private mode on chrome, **sometimes** 2 or 3 images or 1 image and 1 ajax request will fail

and in the console I'll see `net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 (OK)` error

on the network tab the `jpg` file is shown as loaded with `200 OK` status

and preview for the `jpg` is `Image issue de https://...theurltotheimg.jpg`

Is there something I could do on the server to help prevent this issue, or is this a Chrome bug